# Replace list iteration logic with lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have below piece of code to iterate through a list, checking for a particular value and then terminating loop. Can you please suggest a better approach using lambda expression if possible?

```
            for(InvoiceLine invoiceLine : inputInvoice.getInvoiceLines()) {
                Object flag = invoiceLine.getTransientField("ApproveInvoiceLine");
                if(flag != null && ((Boolean)flag)) {
                    approveInv = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I usually prefer to write this kind of `if` as `Boolean.TRUE.equals(flag)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean approveInv = inputInvoice.getInvoiceLines()
                           .stream()
                           .map(x -> x.getTransientField("ApproveInvoiceLine"))
                           .anyMatch(x -> x != null && ((Boolean)x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean approveInv = inputInvoice.getInvoiceLines().stream()
             .filter(i -> invoiceLine.getTransientField("ApproveInvoiceLine")!=null)
             .filter(i -> ((Boolean)invoiceLine.getTransientField("ApproveInvoiceLine"))==true)
             .findFirst()
             .isPresent();
```